# ArraySet in android.util and android.support.v4.util

Tags: android

What is the difference between

[android.util.ArraySet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArraySet.html)

[android.support.v4.util.ArraySet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArraySet.html)

All methods seem to be identical.

Answer (score 3):

As the page indicates, `android.util.ArraySet` was added in API level 23. `android.support.v4.util.ArraySet` is a copy in the [backwards-compatibility support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v4-compat), which allows you to use the class on older devices as far back as API level 4 (increased to level 14 in [recent releases](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#api-versions)).